# iOS UI design: label and text in a same table row

Tags: ios

which component in Xcode could be used to design the UI like the image link below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ujmfjb0pdc36nu/sample.png

Comment: Take one view and set background image and put label and txtField parallel to each other

Comment: Take a look at `UITextField`s `leftView` property. That is how you do it. These are simply 2 `UITextFields`.

Comment: Take a `UITableView` and have customcell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to implement such UI. My simple answer is custom UITableViewCell is preferable.

Full Answer is create subclass of UITableViewCell with two components one UILable other is UITextField. For more idea you can refer [Custom cell using xib](https://medium.com/lessons-learned/9bee5824e722)

Answer (score 0):

You can design YourOwnCustomTableViewCell subclass from UITableViewCell.

In that cell you create label and text like your image.

Hope this link can help you: [Create custom UITableViewCell](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)